# How can I setState for the nested array and objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, multidimensional-array

I need to save a data in this format:

```js
categoryselect: 0: {
  {
    question: [],
    cateName: 'checkbox'
    name: '',
    status: 1
  }
},: 1: {
  {
    question: [],
    cateName: 'checkbox'
    name: '',
    status: 1
  }
},
```

Whenever I click new category I need to create a new object under `categoryselect` and if I click add new question I need to create an object under `categoryselect[0].qustion[]`. I tried like this but it doesn’t seem to do what I want:

```js
this.setState({
  categoryselect: [
    this.state.categoryselect,
    {
      question: [
        ...this.state.categoryselect.question,
        addQuestion
      ]
    }
  ],
});
```

Comment: Any specific reason to choose `categoryselect` as an object with numeric keys ?

Comment: ya categoryselect must be separated as object when the user chooses newcategory is there any better solution ?

Comment: You treat it as an array in the next code block, so do you mean it is an array from the start?

Comment: ya if thats array it will be convenient can we do it using objects @trincot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `categoryselect` should really be an array, like this:

```
categoryselect: [{
    question: [],
    cateName: 'checkbox'
    name: '',
    status: 1
}, {
    question: [],
    cateName: 'checkbox'
    name: '',
    status: 1
}]
```

This will use the same numerical keys, but on top of that you'll have a `length` property and array methods.

When a category needs to be added, just do:

```
this.setState({
    categoryselect: [...this.state.categoryselect, {
        question: [],
        cateName: 'checkbox'
        name: '',
        status: 1
    }]
});
```

... to add a question to the first category, do:

```
this.setState({
    categoryselect: Array.from(this.state.categoryselect, (cat, i) =>
        i != this.state.categoryselect.length-1 ? cat 
             : {...cat, ...{question: [...cat.question, addQuestion]}}
    ) 
});
```

Comment: it satisfies my half need the thing is when a new category is added , the question must be added in the newly created object but now it gets appended in previous category's question

Comment: Hi  slightly modified the code    `i ===(thisArg>0 && thisArg.length-1) ? cat : {...cat, ...{question: [...cat.question, addQuestion]}}` but now I, when i create a new question it gets added in all the categories  @trincot

Comment: instead of arr i jus changed the name i got length of undefined so added `thisArg>0`

Comment: `this.state = {
      categoryselect:[
          {
            question :[],
            cateName:'checkbox',
            name:'',
            status:1
            } ],
}`  this way , i got  arr.length of undefined

Comment: Only issue is while adding question it's getting appended in both category but for me it should get append in particular category

Answer (score 0):

To create the object that you want you can use the following script -

```
 categoryselect = {
  0: {
   {
    question: [],
    cateName: 'checkbox'
    name: '',
    status: 1
   }
  },
  1: {
   {
    question: [],
    cateName: 'checkbox'
    name: '',
    status: 1
   }
  }
 }

var allCategories = categorySelect[Object.keys(categorySelect).length] = {
 question:[...this.state.categoryselect.question,
    addQuestion],
 cateName: 'checkbox'
 name: '',
 status: 1
}

this.setState({
 categoryselect: allCategories
});
```